# python: unicode data is not equal to unicode data

Tags: python

i has some json works like this.

```
>>> j = '{"a":5}'
>>> js = json.loads(j)
>>> for key in js:
...     key
...     type(key)
...     key is unicode('a')
... 
u'a'
<type 'unicode'>
False
```

In my opinion last value of output should be true. Plese helpme to find my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `is` here? You just want to compare:

```
key == unicode('a')
```

or even better:

```
key == u'a'
```

Comment: ok but what is the difference between is and ==. Arent they same and used for same purpose

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce